# equilibrium point in an inverted pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system

The unstable upright position of an Inverted Pendulum on a cart does this corresponds to a Hyperbolic equilibrium point or a non- hyperbolic equilibrium point?

what are some of the properties of a Hyperbolic fixed point?

please give me a lucid explanation on this matter

Comment: I appreciate you for your help.

Comment: I removed your "hyperbolic-geometry" tag and added the "ordinary-differential-equations" tag; this question is mos' def' NOT about hyperbolic geometry. Also, good question, ***+1, endorsed!*** Cheers!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of assistance.

Comment: I am thankful to you

Comment: So what do think regarding the solution ?

Comment: It's pretty complicated due to the pendulum being on a cart.  I'll think about it a bit and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90693/discussion-between-akhil-krishnan-and-robert-lewis).